# Which First - Truncate Table or Drop Index

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Quick question: which is better, to truncate the table first or to drop the indexes first?

Comment: How are you defining 'better'? If you're talking about elapsed time I wouldn't expect it to make much difference, since truncating the table will truncate the indexes too; but benchmarking would show that.

Comment: Better = faster, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Found this in Oracle documentation:

> Removing rows with the TRUNCATE TABLE statement can be more efficient
>   than dropping and re-creating a table. Dropping and re-creating a
>   table invalidates dependent objects of the table, requires you to
>   regrant object privileges on the table, and **requires you to re-create
>   the indexes**, integrity constraints, and triggers on the table and
>   respecify its storage parameters. **Truncating has none of these
>   effects**.

So, it appears that truncating the table updates the indexes.  Therefore, dropping the indexes first would be more efficient.  Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: The same document also says 'when the table is truncated, the index is also truncated' (among other things, depending on the table type, partitioning etc.). It doesn't update the indexes in the same slow way deleting all the records would.

Comment: OK.  It apparently doesn't much matter then.  Still, if I plan to drop the indexes regardless, dropping the indexes would circumvent Oracle needing to truncate the indexes during the truncation of the table.  So, dropping the indexes first still looks better.

Comment: Yes, marginally - not enough to worry about, I'd suggest.